# JavaFX: Is it possible to remove ColumnResizePolicy?

Tags: javafx

I have following problem.

I have a TableView where I can show the data from a file. Now when I changed the size of a column and reload another file, the size of each column is completely destroyed.

**I used following code**

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

My question is, is there a way to remove this ColumnResizePolicy like

> tableView.getColumnResizePolicy().remove(); **or** .clear();

Comment: What do you mean by "_the size of each column is completely destroyed_"? Could you demonstrate with a [mre]?

Comment: @Slaw I found a "solution" for my problem. The problem was no matter how much I enlarged or reduced a column after reloading another file the first column was always half of the tableView size and the other columns were compressed.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem based on your description. Could you provide a [mre], please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution this worked fine.

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

I set this up, everytime before the new file gets loaded and after laoding I'm setting the Policy back to

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```